# C++ std::plus as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I wanna write a class for a `binary indexed array`,

which use two non-type default template parameter, `op` and `identity`.

And need to check the constraint that `op(identity,identity) == identity`.

**My problem is**,

1. **I don't to how to specify `op`, my current solution does not compile**.
   `‘class std::function<T(T, T)>’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter`
2. **how to to check `op(identity,identity) == identity`**, currently I cannot verify, since failed on step 1, maybe `static_assert`?

So currently I use below workaround, but then I cannot specify `op`, eg, `std::multiplies<int>`.
Can anyone tell me how to achieve the goal?

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

// template <typename T = int, std::function<T(T,T)> op = std::plus<T>(), const T identity = T()>
template <typename T = int, const T identity = T()>     // currently workaround
class BIT { // binary indexed array
    const std::function<T(T,T)> op = std::plus<T>();    // currently workaround
public:
    BIT(std::vector<T> value) : value(value), prefixSum(value.size() + 1, identity) {
        for (size_t i = 1; i < prefixSum.size(); ++i) {
            incrementNodeByValue(i, value[i-1]);
        }
        // print(prefixSum,"prefixSum");
    }
    T getSum(size_t i) {
        auto sum = identity;
        while (i) {
            sum = op(sum, prefixSum(i));
            i = firstSmallerAncestor(i);
        }
        return sum;
    }
    void incrementNodeByValue(size_t i, T x) {
        while (i < prefixSum.size()) {
            prefixSum[i] = op(prefixSum[i], x);
            i = firstLargerAncestor(i);
        }
    }
private:
    inline size_t firstLargerAncestor(size_t node) { return node + (node & -node); }
    inline size_t firstSmallerAncestor(size_t node) { return node & (node - 1); }
    std::vector<T> value;
    std::vector<T> prefixSum;
};

int main() {
    auto vec = std::vector<int> {5,1,15,11,52,28,0};
    auto bit = BIT<>(vec);
}
```

Comment: P.S. the above code compiles and works just fine, the first line been commented out is my failed attempt, the two lines which is above and below `class BIT` is workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `std::function` here is a waste and seems to be the source of your confusion.

Note that templates may only be parameterized on typenames and values of integral types (`char`, `int`, `long`, etc). Here you're attempting to parameterize on a value of a `std::function` instantiation, which isn't an integral type. That said, you don't actually need to parameterize on a value in this case.

Because your constructor doesn't accept an argument to initialize the `op` member variable nor is it accessible via the interface, I gather it's safe to assume the operator is known at compile-time, is guaranteed immutable, and default constructible.

As such, I declared the `op` member to be of a parameter type called `operation`.

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

template< typename T = int,
          typename operation = std::plus<T>, 
          const T identity = T() >
class BIT { 
    const operation op = operation();

    static_assert( operation()(identity, identity) == identity );

    std::vector<T> value;
    std::vector<T> prefixSum;

    inline size_t firstLargerAncestor(size_t node) { return node + (node & -node); }
    inline size_t firstSmallerAncestor(size_t node) { return node & (node - 1); }

 public:
    BIT(std::vector<T> value) : 
        value(value), 
        prefixSum(value.size() + 1, identity) {
        for (size_t i = 1; i < prefixSum.size(); ++i) {
            incrementNodeByValue(i, value[i-1]);
        }
    }

    T getSum(size_t i) {
        auto sum = identity;
        while (i) {
            sum = op(sum, prefixSum(i));
            i = firstSmallerAncestor(i);
        }
        return sum;
    }
    void incrementNodeByValue(size_t i, T x) {
        while (i < prefixSum.size()) {
            prefixSum[i] = op(prefixSum[i], x);
            i = firstLargerAncestor(i);
        }
    }
};
```

[live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aywNjj9xf6XMenbn)

As a note, you'll likely want to define an `identity` template elsewhere to parameterized on an operation and value types to default the third parameter here. As is, it seems you'll almost always be defining all three parameters during instantiation.